# Streaming video on a browser from camera pi

Tags: raspicam, streaming-video

Which technology could be the best to stream video on a web browser with the lowest latency in the best quality. Our project is to include a camera pi on a R/C car, so we can drive it in distance. I tried some technology like MJPEG, but we got around 4-5 fps, which is inacceptable for our application. I searched for some tutorial on internet, but I didn't find anything.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there's [UV4L WebRTC](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/). No latency.